# Lumen/Eloquent transaction rollback is not working

Tags: php, eloquent, transactions, lumen

I have this function that permit to save in 4 tables.
I have an error at that line `$stade->save()`  ( it's normal it's a test ) so it should not save the club `$club->save()` that is 4 lines before.

But I don't understand why, the rollback() in the catch is not doing is job and I still have a record in club table. And yes I receive the 409 error so the application is passing by the catch and so by the `DB::rollback()`

Can someone help me please to understand why the rollback is not working ?

```
DB::beginTransaction();
        try {
            $club = new Club();
            $club->login = $request->input('login');
            $club->email = $request->input('email');
            $plainPassword = $request->input('password');
            $club->password = app('hash')->make($plainPassword);
            $club->nom_equipe = $request->input('nom_club');
            $club->nation_id = $request->input('nation_id');
            $club->argent = $this->argentDepart;
            $club->save();

            $stade = new Stade();
            $stade->club_id = $club->id;
            $stade->save();

            $installation = new Installations();
            $installation->club_id = $club->id;
            $installation->save();

            $compositionTactique = new CompositionTactique();
            $compositionTactique->club_id = $club->id;
            $compositionTactique->save();

            DB::commit();

            //return successful response
            return response()->json(['user' => $club->nom_equipe, 'message' => 'CREATED'], 201);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            DB::rollback();

            //return error message
            return response()->json(['message' => $e], 409);
        }
```

Comment: Still no help ?

Comment: Are you using *Laravel* or *Lumen*? Your *question tags* are confusing. In addition, which version of the framework are you using?